# Arguments in python fast.ai function that are not in the function definition?

Tags: python, jupyter, fastai

I have been coming across function calls that use arguments that are not in the function definition. I would like to know how that works (i.e. how the compiler interprets this).

For example, this function call:

```
 interp.plot_confusion_matrix(figsize=(12,12), dpi=60)
```

uses the variables "figsize" and "dpi", but neither of them turn up in the definition of `plot_confusion_matrix`: `help(interp.plot_confusion_matrix)` gives:

```
plot_confusion_matrix(normalize: bool = False, title: str = 'Confusion matrix', 
cmap: Any = 'Blues', norm_dec: int = 2, slice_size: int = None, **kwargs) -> None 
method of fastai.vision.learner.ClassificationInterpretation instance
    Plot the confusion matrix, with `title` and using `cmap`.
```

Why is it not an error to use "figsize" and "dpi" in the function call if they are not arguments of the function? How does this work in python?

Answer (score 1):

Those parameters are taken care of by `**kwargs` in the function definition.
You can look how this is dealt with by [the code in the fastai repo](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/1c3f0a040e1b1d8faed822257d0c7c67ecc7db07/fastai/train.py#L125) and looking for `**kwargs` in the function definition.
Some explanations about how this works can be found on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs.